# Align two images and caption on same row inside bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel with two images along with text that I would like to be on the same row. `display:inline-block;` and `display:inline;` did not come to the rescue like they tend to.

```
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><b>Owner</b></div>
      <div class="panel-body" id="owners">
          <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/40/405b7b5da64cc1dbcb68110ca5e65a9c751b79a0_full.jpg" height="64"><h4>Firav</h4>
          <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/66/66cd4ded6f8bc2761f64c110ff8f8b93e568082e_full.jpg" height="64"><h4>Donnyy</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap-Twitter-3 or 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this -

```css
.panel-body figure{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><b>Owner</b></div>
      <div class="panel-body" id="owners">
        <figure>
          <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/40/405b7b5da64cc1dbcb68110ca5e65a9c751b79a0_full.jpg" height="64"><h4>Firav</h4>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/66/66cd4ded6f8bc2761f64c110ff8f8b93e568082e_full.jpg" height="64"><h4>Donnyy</h4>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write like below code:

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><b>Owner</b></div>
      <div class="panel-body" id="owners">
      <ul> <li><img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/40/405b7b5da64cc1dbcb68110ca5e65a9c751b79a0_full.jpg" height="64">
          <h4>Firav</h4></li>
          <li><img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/66/66cd4ded6f8bc2761f64c110ff8f8b93e568082e_full.jpg" height="64"><h4>Donnyy</h4></li></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#owners ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
#owners li {float:left;margin:0 10px;}
#owners li:first-child{margin-left:0;}
#owners li:last-child{margin-left:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap classes:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><b>Owner</b></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" id="owners">
      <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
        <li class="text-center">
          <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/40/405b7b5da64cc1dbcb68110ca5e65a9c751b79a0_full.jpg" height="64">
          <h4>Firav</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center">
          <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/66/66cd4ded6f8bc2761f64c110ff8f8b93e568082e_full.jpg" height="64">
          <h4>Donnyy</h4>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/3xqvLyt5/2/)